# Android read SMS inbox returns null and zeros for some fields

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I want to read the SMS Inbox, the app is able to fetch the messages but it returns some unexpected results for the body part. Below are screenshots of the undesired output. + the code that produces it.

```
//function to read the SMS inbox
    public void fetchSMS() {
        Uri uriSMSUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSUri, null, null, null, null);
        String sms = "";

        while (c.moveToNext()){
            sms += "From :" + c.getString(2) + " : " + c.getString(11)+"\n";
        }
        txtViewSMS.setText(sms);
    }
```

Output screenshots
[image: null-for-body-fields]

[image: zero-for-body-field]

Kindly assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got the wrong index for the `"body"` column. You should avoid using hard-coded indexes, and instead use the `Cursor#getColumnIndex()` method. For example:

```
sms += "From :" + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")) +
    " : " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body")) + "\n";
```

Also, since you're pulling the entire inbox, which can get rather large, it would help to optimize your method a little bit.

```
public void fetchSMS() {
    final Uri uriSMSUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    final Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final int addressIndex = c.getColumnIndex("address");
        final int bodyIndex = c.getColumnIndex("body");

        do {
            sb.append("From :")
                .append(c.getString(addressIndex))
                .append(" : ")
                .append(c.getString(bodyIndex))
                .append("\n");
        } while (c.moveToNext());

        txtViewSMS.setText(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. I edited my answer to add a few optimizations that should be a little faster, especially if your inbox is rather large. Cheers!

Comment: let me try it, because it actually takes quite some time to load the results

Comment: It's not going to be a huge improvement, but it should be a little faster. You really should be running that method in another thread - e.g., using an `AsyncTask` - so your UI won't hang.

Comment: is there a parameter I can pass to read from a particular sender alone

Comment: The 3rd & 4th arguments in the `query()` call can be used to narrow the selection, but the sender's address would have to be pretty exact.. For example: `query(uriSMSUri, null, "address LIKE ?", new String[]{ "%" + sender }, null)`.